# Pass time interval via variable in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This query returns the value based on given interval time 10.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((TO_DATE('23:20:20','HH24:MI:SS') - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE), 'HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM DUAL;
```

Output:

```
23:10:20
```

I want to pass this minute interval via variable using below code:

```
declare
test1 varchar(30);
begin
test1:=18;
SELECT TO_CHAR((TO_DATE('23:20:20','HH24:MI:SS') - INTERVAL ||test1|| MINUTE), 'HH24:MI:SS') 
 FROM DUAL;
 end;
```

But its not working - error is

> PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "MINUTE": invalid identifier

Please assist me on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
DECLARE
   l_val      NUMBER;
   l_result   VARCHAR2( 20 );
BEGIN
   l_val := 10;

   SELECT TO_CHAR( ( TO_DATE( '23:20:20', 'HH24:MI:SS' ) - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE * l_val ), 'HH24:MI:SS' ) INTO l_result FROM DUAL;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( l_result );
END;
```

Output will be:
23:10:20

Comment: Awesome, nice trick to workaround that it has to be a string literal after INTERVAL.  Hated this limitation. We should be able to pass a hard coded value, variable or a column name.

Answer (score 10):

You can't do that as it has to be a string literal, not a variable. But you can use [the `numtodsinterval()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions117.htm) instead:

```
declare
  test1 number;
begin
  test1:=18;
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('23:20:20','HH24:MI:SS')
   - NUMTODSINTERVAL(test1, 'MINUTE'), 'HH24:MI:SS')
  INTO <something>
  FROM DUAL;
end;
/
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dfd5e/1), including a really simple function version.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `- NUMTODSINTERVAL( test1, 'MINUTE' )`

so your statement is.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((TO_DATE('23:20:20','HH24:MI:SS') - NUMTODSINTERVAL( test1, 'MINUTE' )), 'HH24:MI:SS' )
 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: this should be best answer as i found out.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle INTERVAL using variables

- This post helped me to find a solution for my case.
- I struggled with INTERVAL because I wanted to use variables.
- At the end, this was my solution:

---

```
with VAR as
 (select 1 as AMOUNT,
         'hour' as UNIT
    from DUAL)
```

---

```
select VAR.*,
       SYSTIMESTAMP as ORIGIN,
       SYSTIMESTAMP + interval '1' HOUR as LITERAL_INTERVAL,
       TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP + NUMTODSINTERVAL(VAR.AMOUNT
                                             ,VAR.UNIT)) as VARIABLE_INTERVAL
  from DUAL,
       VAR;
```